# How to do file inputs via node.js using emscripten?

Tags: node.js, webassembly, emscripten

I have a C++ project that I have converted into javascript using emscripten. I need help with implementing file input into the program via node. As I understand it the default file system in emscripten uses preloaded data that can only be done on a web page or web worker. I need mine to work with node.js on the command line.

Looking at the [documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#filesystem-api-persist-data) I see that there's a way to use NODEFS instead of the default MEMFS which should allow me to do this. However, I'm unsure how I'm supposed to go about this. I don't really understand the test code that's provided.

Here's how the file handling is being done in the original C++ project:

```
void InputFile(std::string &fileName)
  {
    std::ifstream in(fileName);

    if (in.fail())
    {
      std::cerr << "ERROR, Could not open " << fileName << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
  }
```

But when I attempt to run the converted program with a file, `node project.js -f test.file` I get the error message: `ERROR, Could not open test.file` meaning that opening the file failed. The original C++ project was able to open the file without any issues, so I know there's not problem with the file itself.

I'm not sure what I have to do to make the converted project work with file inputs, any help would very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

## Explanation

[WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) module, built using [emscripten](https://emscripten.org/), has no information about files in your physical file system. Instead, it uses a virtual file system. All you have to do is to create a link between files on your physical system to the files on the module's virtual system. [NODEFS](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#filesystem-api-nodefs) gives you this opportunity.

## Quick solution

We will start at modifying your C++ code by adding the aforementioned link between physical and virtual file systems using embedded JS code (with [EM_ASM](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-call-javascript-from-native)). First (1), we create a directory `'/temp'` on the virtual file system where all referenced files will be located in. Then (2), we link this new virtual directory with a real physical location (the current working directory `'.'`) where all the referenced files are already.

```cpp
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void InputFile(const std::string &fileName)
{
   EM_ASM(
       FS.mkdir('/temp');                         // (1)
       FS.mount(NODEFS, {root : '.'}, '/temp');); // (2)
   std::ifstream in(std::string("/temp/") + fileName);
   if (in.fail())
   {
      std::cerr << "ERROR, Could not open " << fileName << std::endl;
      exit(1);
   }
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Module)
{
   emscripten::function("InputFile", &InputFile);
}
```

Now, because in the WebAssembly module, we are working with the virtual file systems, and not the physical one, each referenced file from the current directory (the root `'.'`) is actually in the virtual directory previously linked (`'/temp'`). Hence, `'/temp'` directory precedes the name to the referenced file: `std::ifstream in(std::string("/temp/") + fileName);`.

Finally, we can compile this file. We force the synchronized compilation (to make sure the `require` loads the WASM module on time). Moreover, the option `-s EXIT_RUNTIME=1` makes sure that the C++ command `exit(1);` finishes the execution. Also, we need to link [Embind](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html) (`--bind`) and [NODEFS](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#filesystem-api-nodefs) (`-lnodefs.js`):

```sh
emcc project.cpp -o project.js -s WASM_ASYNC_COMPILATION=0 -s EXIT_RUNTIME=1  --bind -lnodefs.js
```

## Testing

To test the WebAssembly module with the same calling convention as you have mentioned, we can use the following `test.js` script:

```js
var Module = require('./project.js');

if (process.argv[3] && process.argv[2] === '-f') {
   const filename = process.argv[3];
   Module.InputFile(filename);
} else {
   console.log('Pass the file with -f flag!');
}
```

To run the file, all you have to do is this: `node test.js -f test.file`

## Comment

This approach works well if the referenced files are in the current working directory. In the case they are not, you could modify the code of the `InputFile` to extract the directory in which the `fileName` is, and then, mount the real-to-virtual directory accordingly.

Comment: Can we do this in JS, without touching the original C file? (In my case, I have a big project I compiled with emconfigure and emmake, and the resulting output.js is looking for `/etc/path` and I'd love to provide the mapping between the virtual disk and the real one in JavaScript for Node.js.)

Comment: Figured out how to do this via `-s NODERAWFS=1` flag for `emcc`.