# How to compile C file with Library imports to webassembly file (Emscripten)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webassembly, emscripten, json-c

I have a simple C program that needs to parse Json data. For that I have imported JSON-C library. My C code is -

```
#include"json.h"
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int addnumbers(int a, int b) {
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct json_object *parsed_json;
    struct json_object *name;
    struct json_object *age;
    struct json_object *friends;
    struct json_object *friend;
    size_t n_friends;

    size_t i;

    fp = fopen("test.json","r");
    fread(buffer, 1024, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    parsed_json = json_tokener_parse(buffer); 

    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "name", &name);
    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "age", &age);
    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "friends", &friends);

    printf("Name: %s\n", json_object_get_string(name));
    printf("Age: %d\n", json_object_get_int(age));

    n_friends = json_object_array_length(friends);


    for(i=0;i<n_friends;i++) {
        friend = json_object_array_get_idx(friends, i);
        // printf("%lu. %s\n",i+1,json_object_get_string(friend));
    }
    return n_friends;
}
```

Process I followed :-
Compiled the library(specifically json.h file) into bit code using command-

```
emcc json.h -o json.bc
```

and then compiled my C program using -

```
emcc json.c -o j_plumbing.bc -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap'] -s ENVIRONMENT='web,worker' -s EXPORT_ES6=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s USE_ES6_IMPORT_META=0
```

Then together I compiled both the files to get wasm file with this command :-

```
emcc json.bc j_plumbing.bc -o js_plumbing.js -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap'] -g4 -s LINKABLE=1 -s EXPORT_ALL=1 -s ENVIRONMENT='web,worker' -s EXPORT_ES6=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s USE_ES6_IMPORT_META=0
```

and this is how I'm calling it from Vue file

```
public draw_outline() {
        Module().then(myModule => {
            console.log(myModule)
            const result = myModule.ccall('addnumbers',
                'number',
                ['number', 'number'],
                [4, 6]);
            console.log("Value from wasm file", result);
        });
    }
but this is the error I'm getting-

002210ee:1 Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: function signature mismatch
    at fclose (wasm-function[524]:0x1a777)
    at addnumbers (wasm-function[148]:0x6a45)
    at Module._addnumbers (webpack-internal:///./src/components/js_plumbing.js:1098:4989)
    at Object.ccall (webpack-internal:///./src/components/js_plumbing.js:199:628)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Extraction.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&:128:31)
    at Object.Module.onRuntimeInitialized (webpack-internal:///./src/components/js_plumbing.js:1109:95)
    at doRun (webpack-internal:///./src/components/js_plumbing.js:1117:140)
    at run (webpack-internal:///./src/components/js_plumbing.js:1117:436)
    at runCaller (webpack-internal:///./src/components/js_plumbing.js:1113:15)
    at removeRunDependency (webpack-internal:///./src/components/js_plumbing.js:373:843)
```

Can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

If you read closely the error and the call stack, you can notice that the problem originated in the `fclose()` function. A [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) module generated using [emscripten](https://emscripten.org) has its [virtual file system](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/files/file_systems_overview.html#file-system-overview) which does not understand the local file system on your machine. Therefore, any access to local files will fail, as the `fp = fopen("test.json","r");` does and it returns `NULL`. This `NULL`-value of `fp` pointer is the reason for the error of `fclose(fp)`.

Due to my inability to work with your code (sorry) I have replicated the error in a slightly different setting, but after the quick solution!

## Quick solution

Map virtual file system of WebAssembly/[emscripten](https://emscripten.org) to local file system using e.g. [NODEFS](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#filesystem-api-nodefs). You can find more information about this solution in my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60510997/1319478.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

void test_fun()
{
   FILE *fp;
   EM_ASM(
       FS.mkdir('/temp');
       FS.mount(NODEFS, {root : '.'}, '/temp'););
   fp = fopen("temp/test.json", "r");
   fclose(fp);
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Module)
{
   emscripten::function("test_fun", &test_fun);
}
```

## The simplest replication of the error

This example code tries to close a file with a pointer of `NULL` value.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

void test_fun()
{
   fclose(NULL);
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Module)
{
   emscripten::function("test_fun", &test_fun);
}
```

If you compile this example with additional debug information `-g`:

```sh
emcc example.cpp -o example.js --bind -s WASM_ASYNC_COMPILATION=0 -g
```

And then try to execute a test script `node test.js`, where `test.js` is as follows:

```js
var Module = require('./example.js');

Module.test_fun();
```

Then, what you get is the same error:

```
RuntimeError: function signature mismatch
    at fclose (wasm-function[32]:127)
    at test_fun() (wasm-function[17]:9)
    ...
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I haven't been able to test this yet but I'm convinced this is the solution. I appreciate your help. Thank you.